# How to fix SFML "failed to load Image" in c++ ? (junk characters) (Resolve)

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a problem with sfml... everything was working fine but now I can't load any image. Whenever I try, I have the error "Failed to load Image" with a bunch of junk characters...

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! This sounds like a very annoying problem and we would love to help, but this really isn't enough information to know how to help you. Please create a [mcve], including the shortest possible code snippet that demonstrates the error, and details of your build system, IDE, or compiler invocation.

Comment: A shot in the dark: The string you're passing to `sf::Image::loadFromFile` is corrupted. Please show how you're calling this function and what you're passing

Comment: Thank you. I found how to fix it. I changed the compiler, because mySQL wasn't working with the original compiler. But it wasn't the good one with SFML, so I changed it for another. Thank you.

Comment: With what compiler did it not work? And which compiler are you using now? It sounds like you may be relying on undefined- or implementation-defined behaviour. SFML should work with most recent compilers, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are linking correct versions of sfml libs.

If you are buildign in debug mode, make sure to link debug versions of lib files (*-d.lib).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).